# Heroku deployment successful for reactjs website but still shows "application error"

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

I am trying to deploy my simple reactjs 16.8.6  with webpack 4 on heroku.

I have tried including lazy loading for components and have seen and tried many solutions on stackoverflow,but none solve my problem.I do not understand where is the problem looking at my heroku log file.Its just warnings and node modules error but it works on my local.I am using heroku for the first time,so is there something i need to do or add for heroku,I have followed all deployment steps correctly ,it shows deployed successfully but still shows "application error" when trying to open website on heroku.

BUILD LOG FILE:

```js
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.1.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.9.0
       
       Resolving node version 10.1.0...
       Downloading and installing node 10.1.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.9.0 (replacing 5.6.0)...
       npm 6.9.0 installed
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       audited 50112 packages in 16.01s
       found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > example@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_dc8013021bc209e1bac89229b0579201
       > webpack --mode production
       
       Hash: e7d503a89b51cddf1705
       Version: webpack 4.29.6
       Time: 13409ms
       Built at: 2019-03-31 11:25:04
                                      Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                               ./index.html  1.72 KiB          [emitted]         
       062ea122b3e9a6a664abcb921271c9ad.png   323 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
       3d7380a833cd5572414470a8c719cdbf.png   312 KiB          [emitted]  
                                favicon.ico  3.78 KiB          [emitted]         
                               js/bundle.js   596 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
     
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         40fc28864e80faa971922ff123ffc1e0.png (473 KiB)
         062ea122b3e9a6a664abcb921271c9ad.png (323 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (596 KiB)
             js/bundle.js
       
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
            1 asset
           Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
           [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html 1.85 KiB {0} [built]
           [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 878 bytes {0} [built]
           [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
               + 1 hidden module
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 168 packages and audited 41359 packages in 15.133s
       found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Change to Node.js build process 
       Heroku has begun executing the "build" script defined in package.json
       during Node.js builds.
       Read more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 54.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v4
   https://example.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

LOGS:

```js
2019-03-31T13:53:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-31T13:53:01.574617+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-31T13:53:04.331946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-31T13:53:04.338921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-31T13:53:04.141111+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-31T13:53:04.141195+00:00 app[web.1]: > example@0.1.0 start /app
2019-03-31T13:53:04.141202+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --open --mode production
2019-03-31T13:53:04.141203+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-31T13:53:04.148500+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
2019-03-31T13:53:04.155568+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-03-31T13:53:04.155913+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-03-31T13:53:04.156178+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-03-31T13:53:04.156434+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-03-31T13:53:04.158166+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! exampleb@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open --mode production`
2019-03-31T13:53:04.158331+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-03-31T13:53:04.158620+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-03-31T13:53:04.158829+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the example@0.1.0 start script.
2019-03-31T13:53:04.159067+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-03-31T13:53:04.167285+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-31T13:53:04.167520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-03-31T13:53:04.167653+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-03-31T13_53_04_160Z-debug.log
2019-03-31T13:53:04.314503+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-03-31T13:53:11.798582+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-31T13:53:13.967668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-31T13:53:13.843741+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-31T13:53:13.843761+00:00 app[web.1]: > example@0.1.0 start /app
2019-03-31T13:53:13.843763+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --open --mode production
2019-03-31T13:53:13.843765+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-31T13:53:13.860315+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
2019-03-31T13:53:13.865559+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-03-31T13:53:13.865825+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-03-31T13:53:13.866210+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-03-31T13:53:13.866520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-03-31T13:53:13.869744+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! example@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open --mode production`
2019-03-31T13:53:13.869747+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-03-31T13:53:13.869749+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-03-31T13:53:13.869750+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the example@0.1.0 start script.
2019-03-31T13:53:13.869753+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-03-31T13:53:13.877763+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-31T13:53:13.877900+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-03-31T13:53:13.877990+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-03-31T13_53_13_870Z-debug.log
2019-03-31T13:53:13.931427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-03-31T13:53:18.414100+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=example.herokuapp.com request_id=a5dcb4cd-7369-4420-81c9-f146ca727c9a fwd="103.21.238.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-31T13:53:19.463720+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=example.herokuapp.com request_id=31aeca36-43ac-4b5a-9092-a1e24fbf17cb fwd="103.21.238.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "biz-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.1.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-css-modules": "^4.7.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-mobile-store-button": "0.0.4",
    "react-particles-js": "^2.5.1",
    "react-responsive": "^6.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --dev",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
module.exports = {
   entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
     },
      module:{
         rules:[{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: { compact:false,presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"], 
            plugins:["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]}
         },
         {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
     },
        
    {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
   
    ]
     },
     plugins: [
      new HWP({
        template: path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'),
        filename: "./index.html",
        favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
      })
   ]
}
```

I created my react app using create-react-app and I have also tried deleting and reinstalling my node modules using npm start.

Comment: Your "application error" message probably comes with an [HTTP 500 response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error). This is a generic server-side error message. On its own it barely tells us anything. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. "Its just warnings and node modules error"—those warnings and errors are _important_. Please [edit] your question and add them. We can't help you without seeing what errors are actually being generated. Please see [ask].

Comment: @Chris but that is my log file in heroku...is there a more detailed error message, if yes then where?Where should i check the error logs?

Comment: That's your _build_ log. Run `heroku logs` to see recent runtime logs. (You should probably also configure a logger on your application that outputs to `stdout` or `stderr`, but that might not be necessary to fix this problem.)

Comment: @Chris Ok,I have updated my runtime logs above.Please check.

Comment: And your `package.json`?

Comment: @Chris I updated it above.

Comment: you should not use webpack-dev-server to serve your application on heroku. The problem starts there, its just for development. Probably heroku could not find webpack-dev-server

Comment: i created express server file and added the "node server.js" in start in my scripts in package.json and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue is that Heroku doesn't install `devDependencies`, and you're using one of your `devDependencies` in your `start` script:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development"
```

But `webpack-dev-server` *should* be in `devDependencies`. You shouldn't use it in production. Instead, your `start` script should probably be something like

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

(though the exact details will depend on your application). Try updating your `package.json` accordingly, committing, and pushing to Heroku again.